# Виртуальные функции С++. Не компилируется

Tags: c++, классы, виртуальная-функция

Возникла проблема, данный код не компилируется, и в ошибке белиберда. В чем проблема? Так как делал по документации [Майкрософта](https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/0y01k918.aspx). Компилировал в [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MzoU/1).

Текст ошибки:

> ```
> /tmp/cc5W12md.o: In function `Abstract::Abstract()':
> main.cpp:(.text._ZN8AbstractC2Ev[_ZN8AbstractC5Ev]+0x9): undefined reference to `vtable for Abstract'
> /tmp/cc5W12md.o:(.rodata._ZTI7Complex[_ZTI7Complex]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Abstract'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> exit status 1
> ```

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual float Norma();
};

class Complex: public Abstract
{
public:
    Complex() {}
    float Norma() {}
};

int main() 
{
   int n = 2;
   Complex* number = new Complex[n];
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь в дальнейшем приводить код в формате [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Начнем с того, что ваши функции `Norma()` и `NumberC` объявлены как возвращающие `float`, но в них даже нет оператора `return`...

Далее, или у вас

```
virtual float Abstract::Norma();
```

в абстрактном классе, и тогда поставьте `= 0` после точкой с запятой, или она *не* в абстрактном классе, и тогда определите ее...

У вас класс, по всей видимости, задуман как абстрактный, но это нигде не используется - так что вы вообще можете его выбросить :) Если он абстрактный - то в нем должна быть хотя бы одна чисто абстрактная виртуальная функция (которая `=0`).

Answer (score 3):

В вашей реализации функция Abstract::Norma хоть и виртуальная, но требует реализации, т.е. наличия тела функции. Чтобы использовать класс Abstract как интерфейс, сделайте функцию **Norma** чисто виртуальной

```
virtual float Norma() = 0;
```

Comment: Обязательно виртуальную ф-цию приравнивать к 0?

Comment: Нет. Но если не "приравнять к нулю", то надо писать тело функции. Просто виртуальная функция требует наличия реализации.